# microsoft team custom tabs refuse to connect to page

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am trying to develop a custom app with a tab I have installed the app successfully but when i open the tab it states connection refused to the website from where the content has to be displayed. I am a newbie to Microsoft team app. Below is the manifest.json.

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json- 
    schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "isFullScreen": true,
  "id": "e23cbae9-8598-4b64-bd35-d8dcd9552372",
  "packageName": "com.uber",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Mphasis",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.mphasis.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.mphasis.com",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.mphasis.com"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "uberApp",
    "full": "Uber App1"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "testing app",
    "full": "uber test app"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "12346",
      "name": "mytab",
      "contentUrl": "https://capgemini.com/in-en/careers/",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "capgemini.com"
  ]
}'''
```

Comment: Did you try giving other public url's? are you on firewall restricted network? Are you on sigined in with your official account in Teams?

Comment: Hi Manish, Yes i have tried using other public url's and I have created a o365 development subscription and accessing team from o365 app's. The page is not getting loaded in the iframe but when i click on the globe icon it opens the webpage of that tab in a new windows outside teams

Comment: The page must be iframe-able to open in teams, not all pages can open in teams. Please make a page iframe-able.

Comment: Hi Manish, Can please help how to make a page iframe-able. As far as i know we can just specify the page link in <iframe> tag and the page will open in iframe. Can you please check the manifest.json and try to recreate that in your machine and see if there is anyerror.

Comment: Websites must be frameable always to load in teams as tab. Your content url cannot be iframed in teams. I would suggest you to build a webpage(a sample html) and try loading it in teams.

Comment: Hi @Bindu, Your web page uses `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` you should remove the `X-Frame-Options` header or use the `ALLOW-FROM URL`, the value it should be equals `https://microsoft.com` or `https://teams.microsoft.com`. Please test it, which one is the correct value.